# How to pass the webservice results as an input list for a batch apex class?

Tags: batch

i read the documentation and it has been given like the one given below.

```
global class UpdateInvoiceFields implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
   global final String Query;
   global final String Entity;
   global final String Field;
   global final String Value;

   global UpdateInvoiceFields(String q, String e, String f, String v){
             Query=q; Entity=e; Field=f;Value=v;
   }

   global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
      return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
   }

   global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, 
                       List<sObject> scope){
      for(Sobject s : scope){s.put(Field,Value); 
      }      update scope;
   }

   global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){

   }

}
```

also, the code snippet which is used to invoke the above batch is given below,

```
// Query for 10 invoice statements
String q = 'SELECT Description__c FROM Invoice_Statement__c LIMIT 10';
String e = 'Invoice_Statement__c';
String f = 'Description__c';
String v = 'Updated description';
Id batchInstanceId = Database.executeBatch(new UpdateInvoiceFields(q,e,f,v), 5);
```

Instead of using a query to invoke a batch, i need to send a custom list which is not a sobject to the batch to start with. Is that possible? Any ideas?

Thanks,
Baskaran

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Would be great to learn more about what is driving your requirement to update fields this way (third party system?). But it's definitely possible, you can hand in a non-SObject iterable like this:

```
public class InvoiceFieldUpdater implements Database.Batchable<FieldDto> {

    /**
     * You will need to massage the response
     * from your web service into this class.
     */
    public class FieldDto {
        String id;
        String entity;
        String field;
        String value;
    }

    private List<FieldDto> dtos;

    public InvoiceFieldUpdater(List<FieldDto> dtos) {
        this.dtos = dtos;
    }

    public Iterable<FieldDto> start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        return this.dtos;
    }

    /**
     * You can dynamically instantiate the correct
     * type of SObject for performing the update.
     */
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<FieldDto> scope) {
        FieldDto dto = scope[0];

        SObject invoice = (SObject)Type.forName(dto.entity).newInstance();
        invoice.put(dto.field, dto.value);
        invoice.Id = dto.id;
        update invoice;
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {}
}
```

**Example usage:**

```
List<InvoiceFieldUpdater.FieldDto> dtos = new List<InvoiceFieldUpdater.FieldDto>();
InvoiceFieldUpdater.FieldDto dto;

dto = new InvoiceFieldUpdater.FieldDto();
dto.id = '001d000000UaWiX';
dto.entity = 'Account';
dto.field = 'Name';
dto.value = 'Herp Derp Doop';
dtos.add(dto);

dto = new InvoiceFieldUpdater.FieldDto();
dto.id = '001d000000UaWiZ';
dto.entity = 'Account';
dto.field = 'Name';
dto.value = 'Foo Bar Baz';
dtos.add(dto);

dto = new InvoiceFieldUpdater.FieldDto();
dto.id = '001d000000UaWiW';
dto.entity = 'Account';
dto.field = 'Name';
dto.value = 'One Two Three';
dtos.add(dto);

Database.executeBatch(new InvoiceFieldUpdater(dtos), 1);
```

Comment: few questions, 1. Does the class FieldDto need to implement Iterable interface ?   2. Any reason why all fields of FieldDto are public ?

Comment: 1. no need, as it iterates over a List<Dto> 2. good point, private is ok @apn